# If $a, b, ... e$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$, if $ax + by = c$ has the same solution set of $ax + dy = e$, then these equations are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I have an exercise in my last assignment for liner algebra class, where I have to prove that 2 equations are the same.

---

The problem is the following:

> Prove that, if $a, b, ... e$ are real numbers and $a \neq 0$, if $ax + by = c$ has
>   the same *solution set* of $ax + dy = e$, then these equations are the
>   same.
>
> What if $a = 0$?

First of all, I have some problems understanding exactly the problem.

- For solution set of an equation, I suppose it indicates all the possible values for $x$ and $y$, such that the equation is true. But I am don't exactly know how would I turn this in mathematical terms that can help me solving this problem. We only know that if we insert the same pair $x$ and $y$ in both equations, we obtain an equality, like $1 = 1$ or $0 = 0$.
- I have also problems understanding what does it mean to 2 equations be the same. Does this mean that they have the same left and right side expression of the equal sign, or it simply means that they have the same *solution set* (then I would not have anything to prove, since this is the assumption).

What I have tried to do is to make a system of equations (even though I am not seeing why should this help me):

$$
\begin{cases}
ax + by = c \\
ax + dy = e
\end{cases}
$$

I can for example use the first equation to find $x$ respect to $y$:

$$x = \frac{c - by}{a}$$

Replace this $x$ in the second equation to find $y$:

$$a(\frac{c - by}{a}) + dy = e$$
$$c - by + dy = e$$
$$y(b + d) = e - c$$
$$y = \frac{e - c}{(b + d)}$$

If I replace this $y$ in the first equation, I obtain (if I did not do any mistake):

$$x = \frac{cd - be}{a(d - b)}$$

Sincerely, I am not seeing why should this help me, and even if I am on the right track or not.

---

For $a = 0$, both equations result in:

$$
\begin{cases}
by = c \\
dy = e
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
y = \frac{c}{b} \\
y = \frac{e}{d}
\end{cases}
$$

So, when $a = 0$, I suppose that for both equations being equal, $\frac{c}{b}$ must be equal to $\frac{e}{d}$.

Comment: Subtract the two equations to get $Ay=B$ for some $A,B$. This should hold for all $y$ in the solution set... conclude about what $A,B$ needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\ne 0$ we have for the solutions:
$$
x_1=\dfrac{c-by}{a} \; \land \;x_2=\dfrac{e-dy}{a} \quad \forall y 
$$
since we want $x_1=x_2$ we have:
$$
(c-by = e-dy) \Rightarrow y(b-d)=c-e \quad \forall y
$$
so, for $y=0$ gives: $c=e$ and for $y\ne 0$ gives $b=d$.

The case $a=0$ is solved in OP.

Comment: You have $y(b-d)=0$ from the previous case. I.e. It must be valid for $y=0$ **and** $y \ne 0$.

Comment: No! The equation $y(b-d)=c-e$ **must** be verifed when $y=0$ and this gives $c=e$, **and** when $y\ne 0$, this means that we **must** have $c=e$ also in this case  (otherwise the first is not verified) so $y(b-d)=0$ gives $b=d$.

Comment: There are two distict case in the sense that $a=0$ you can not find $x_1$ and $x_2$ as in my answer. The case $a\ne 0$ is really only one case.

Comment: You are confusing the logical statements **and** , **or**. In this case we have an **and**. If you put $c\ne e$ in the second case you are using an **or** condition.

Comment: because you want that **all** the solution set is the same for the two equations, and this means that $y=0$ **and** $y \ne 0$ must be verified at the same time.

Comment: obviously what we assume first has no matter! **and** is commutative.